# Build failing for 'ionic build ios' on OSX 10.12.1

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ionic-framework, build

So this is a brand new Mac Air.. running Sierra.

When i run
    ionic build ios

i get

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/foo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/homepocket-gtpsstxtfgknjdgahozlqhgfgmmi/Build/Intermediates/homepocket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/homepocket.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o homepocket/Classes/AppDelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

```
CompileC /Users/foo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/homepocket-gtpsstxtfgknjdgahozlqhgfgmmi/Build/Intermediates/homepocket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/homepocket.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainViewController.o homepocket/Classes/MainViewController.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

(2 failures)

Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/foo/workspace/myproject_mobile/myproject/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,myproject.xcworkspace,-scheme,myproject,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5s,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/foo/workspace/myproject_mobile/myproject/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/foo/workspace/myproject_mobile/myproject/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

I installed latest xcode via apple store.
I set the machine to dev mode via xcode ide.
I've ran the emulate through xcode.
I can successfully 'ionic build android'  as well as emulate.
I've also run sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Because i was seeing 
    Error: xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

.. mind you all of this is a fresh box from Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding this..  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found-in-xcode-7-1-beta/32232/47

The solution for me was ...

```
ionic platform remove ios
ionic platform add ios@3.9.2
ionic prepare ios
```

Then i could build ios.